# What is the optical illusion called where our sun seems to disappear from view and then rise on the third day? And where can it be viewed from?

Tags: optics

What is the optical illusion called where our sun seems to disappear for 3 days and then rise again into view on the third day? And where can it be viewed from?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_night

Answer (score 2):

I do not know about optical illusions but there are 72 hour nights (refraction taken into account) by coincidence in 72 degrees [latitude](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Polar+Night).

> Polar Night
>
> a night lasting more than 24 hours, occurring in polar regions north of the arctic circle and south of the antarctic circle. At points in the northern hemisphere with a geographic latitude ϕ, the sun will not rise above the horizon at certain times of the year. This occurs whenever the sun, in its apparent annual motion along the ecliptic, enters an area of the sky that is not visible at that given latitude.

Its name is "polar night at latitude 72 degrees".

Have a look at this [map](http://www.mapsofworld.com/world-maps/world-map-with-latitude-and-longitude.html) to see the location where the three days happen, northenmost parts of Greenland, Canada and Russia.